# Facing issue at the time of Web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract reviews from Glass door. However I am facing issues. Please follow my codes below-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

url = requests.get("https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/The-Wonderful-Company-Reviews-E1005987.htm?sort.sortType=RD&sort.ascending=false&countryRedirect=true", headers=headers)

urlContent =BeautifulSoup(url.content,"lxml")
print(urlContent)

review = urlContent.find_all('a',class_='reviewLink')
review

title = []
for i in range(0,len(review)):
    title.append(review[i].get_text())
title
rating= urlContent.find_all('div',class_='v2__EIReviewsRatingsStylesV2__ratingNum v2__EIReviewsRatingsStylesV2__small')

score=[]
for i in range(0,len(rating)):
    score.append(rating[i].get_text())

rev_pros=urlContent.find_all("span",{"data-test":"pros"})

pros=[]
for i in range(0,len(rev_pros)):
    pros.append(rev_pros[i].get_text())
pros

rev_cons=urlContent.find_all("span",{"data-test":"cons"})

cons=[]
for i in range(0,len(rev_cons)):
    cons.append(rev_cons[i].get_text())
cons

advse=urlContent.find_all("span",{"data-test":"advice-management"})
advse
advise=[]
for i in range(0,len(advse)):
    advise.append(advse[i].get_text())
advise
location=urlContent.find_all('span',class_='authorLocation')
location
job_location=[]
for i in range(0,len(location)):
    job_location.append(location[i].get_text())
job_location

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()

df['Review Title']=title
df['Overall Score']=score
df['Pros']=pros
df['Cons']=cons
df['Jobs_Location']=job_location
df['Advise to Mgmt']=advise
```

Here I am facing two challenges-

1. Unable to extract anything for 'advse'(used for 'Advise to
   Managemnt').
2. Getting error when I use 'Job Location' as a column in the data
   frame.`(ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index)`.
   For this error my finding was- there were ten rows for
   other columns however for 'Job Location' there are less rows as
   location not disclosed in some reviews.

Can any body help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with advse? Does it return an empty list? ...as for the missing locations, it seems the html just doesn't have that element in all divs... Your code is searching for columns in the whole soup, try to search by rows, if that makes sense... find a parent class that holds all the fields and collect the data row-wise

Comment: Yes. advse returns empty list

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to find a `<div>` that encloses each of the reviews and then extract all the information needed from it before moving to the next. This would make it easier to deal with the case where information is missing in some reviews.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

url = requests.get("https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/The-Wonderful-Company-Reviews-E1005987.htm?sort.sortType=RD&sort.ascending=false&countryRedirect=true", headers=headers)
urlContent = BeautifulSoup(url.content,"lxml")

get_text = lambda x: x.get_text(strip=True) if x else ""
entries = []

for entry in urlContent.find_all('div', class_='row mt'):
    review = entry.find('a', class_="reviewLink")
    rating = entry.find('div',class_='v2__EIReviewsRatingsStylesV2__ratingNum v2__EIReviewsRatingsStylesV2__small')
    rev_pros = entry.find("span", {"data-test":"pros"})
    rev_cons = entry.find("span", {"data-test":"cons"})
    location = entry.find('span', class_='authorLocation')
    advice = entry.find("span", {"data-test":"advice-management"})

    entries.append([
        get_text(review),
        get_text(rating),
        get_text(rev_pros),
        get_text(rev_cons),
        get_text(location),
        get_text(advice)
    ])

columns = ['Review Title', 'Overall Score', 'Pros', 'Cons', 'Jobs_Location', 'Advise to Mgmt']
df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

The `get_text()` function ensures that if nothing was returned (i.e. `None`) then an empty string is returned.

---

You will need to improve your logic for extracting the advice. The information for the whole page is held inside a `<script>` tag. One of them holds the JSON data. The advice information is not moved into HTML until a user clicks on it, as such it would need to be extracted from the JSON. If this approach is used, then it would also make sense to extract all of the other information also directly from the JSON.

To do this, locate all the `<script>` tags and determine which contains the reviews. Convert the JSON into a Python data structure (using the JSON library). Now locate the reviews, for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

url = requests.get("https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/The-Wonderful-Company-Reviews-E1005987.htm?sort.sortType=RD&sort.ascending=false&countryRedirect=true", headers=headers)
urlContent = BeautifulSoup(url.content,"lxml")

entries = []

for script in urlContent.find_all('script'):
    text = script.text
    
    if "appCache" in text:
        # extract the JSON from the script tag
        data = json.loads(text[text.find('{'): text.rfind('}') + 1])

        # Go through all keys in the dictionary and pick those containing reviews
        for key, value in data['apolloState'].items():
            if ".reviews." in key and "links" not in key:

                location = value['location']
                city = location['id'] if location else None
                
                entries.append([
                    value['summary'],
                    value['ratingOverall'],
                    value['pros'],
                    value['cons'],
                    city,
                    value['advice']
                ])
                

columns = ['Review Title', 'Overall Score', 'Pros', 'Cons', 'Jobs_Location', 'Advise to Mgmt']
df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

This would give you a dataframe as follows:

```
            Review Title  Overall Score                   Pros                   Cons Jobs_Location         Advise to Mgmt
0  Upper management n...              3  Great benefits, lo...  Career advancement...  City:1146821  Listen to your emp...
1                  Sales              2  Good atmosphere lo...  Drive was very far...          None                   None
2  As an organization...              2  Free water and goo...  Not a lot of diver...          None                   None
3    Great place to grow              4  If your direct man...  Owners are heavily...  City:1146821                   None
4          Great Company              5  Great leadership, ...  To grow and move u...  City:1146821                   None
5  Lots of opportunit...              5  This is a fast pac...  There's a sense of...  City:1146821  Continue listening...
6  Interesting work i...              3  Working with great...  High workload and ...          None                   None
7              Wonderful              5  This  company care...  The drive, but we ...  City:1146577  Continue growing y...
8             Horrendous              1  The pay was fairly...  Culture of abuse a...  City:1146821  Upper management l...
9  Upper Leadership a...              1  Strong Company, fu...  You don't have a f...  City:1146577  You get rid of fol...
```

It would help if you added `print(data)` to see the whole structure of the data being returned. The only issue with this approach is a further lookup would be needed to convert the city ID into an actual location. That information is also contained in the JSON.